# Can Deeplab V3+ run on WINDOWS?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, image-segmentation

Can DeeplabV3+ run on windows 10 (with tensorflow-gpu)?

win10 has a ubuntu subsystem, but it seems can't use gpu.

Is there any methods?